# Trying to find out where a screenshot of an "Empty Pages" report came from. Doesn't look like a Google tool

Tags: seo, seo-audit

Screenshot for reference. Anyone recognize this?[image: screenshot of Empty Pages report]

The screenshot came from a client via email.

A client took the screenshot, and then sent it to me in an email.

The problem is that I do not know which SEO audit tool this came from.

I am trying to find out which SEO audit tool this report came from, because I do not know.

Comment: Please share how you received it

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.